# Tag helpers do not resolve when view is outside the Views folder

Tags: asp.net-core, tag-helpers

With `Asp .Net 5 beta 6` the tag helpers do not resolve when the view is located outside the `Views` folder. The folder structure that I would like is one based on function rather than on file types. The controller, view models and views for a particular function I would like grouped together in a folder that reflects the controller name. Here is an example of the folder structure that I would like in the project:

```
 UI
   - Account
        - AccountController.cs
        - AccountViewModels.cs
        - Login.cshtml
        - Register.cshtml
   - Students
        - StudentsController.cs
        - StudentsViewModels.cs
        - CaptureStudent.cshtml
```

To accomplish this I have created a custom view engine:

```
public class CustomUIViewEngine : RazorViewEngine
{
    public CustomUIViewEngine(IRazorPageFactory pageFactory,
       IRazorViewFactory viewFactory,
       IOptions<RazorViewEngineOptions> optionsAccessor,
       IViewLocationCache viewLocationCache) :
       base(pageFactory, viewFactory, optionsAccessor, viewLocationCache)
    {
    }
    public override IEnumerable<string> ViewLocationFormats
    {
        get
        {
            var viewLocationFormats = base.ViewLocationFormats
            .Union(new string[] { "~/UI/{1}/{0}.cshtml" });
            return viewLocationFormats;
        }
    }
}
```

Which I register in `startup.cs` as follows:

```
services.AddMvc().ConfigureMvcViews(options =>
        {
            options.ViewEngines.Clear();
            options.ViewEngines.Add(typeof(CustomUIViewEngine));
        });
```

This custom view engine does work and the view gets located and rendered, with the only problem being that the `tag helpers` are not correctly rendered, so instead of seeing this:

```
<form method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="/Account/Login">
```

I am seeing this in the rendered source:

```
<form asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Login" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
```

Does anyone know why the `tag helpers` are not rendering correctly when the view is located outside the Views folder and if there is any way to correct this in an `Asp.Net 5` web application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you adding your TH's in the *_ViewImports* file, and if so are the **using** statements being recognized? Have you tried adding the @addTagHelper directly to a view?

Some of this is mentioned in my [Authoring Tag Helpers](http://docs.asp.net/projects/mvc/en/latest/views/tag-helpers/authoring.html) 
I go into to detail on inheritance hierarchy, adding, removing in an upcoming article.

Comment: Thanks for the help RickAnd. :) Yes, adding the @addTagHelper directive to the view resolved the problem as did moving the _ViewImports folder from its default location to the root of my UI folder. Problem solved. Thanks!

Comment: @BruceHill awesome. Would you mind marking this as the answered question?

Comment: It would helpful if the docs could include some more info regarding `_ViewImports` possible file locations if you are not using the default project structure (e.g., what if all views are not under a common `Views` folder?). It appears that if you place `_ViewImports` at the root of the project, it will apply to all views in all folders, so this handles that scenario, but the docs don't currently seem to cover that.